# Spring and Thymeleaf session attributes

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I`m creating my first Spring blog and trying to set logged user full name in navbar. Unfortunately sec:authentication="name" gives me user email and ${user.fullname) does not render anything. I figured out to put following code inside in an Article controller

```
 @GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    List<Article> articles = this.articleRepository.findAll();

   Object currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

   if ("anonymousUser".equals(currentUser.toString())) {
       model.addAttribute("username","GUEST");
   } else {
       UserDetails user = (UserDetails) currentUser;
       String name = this.userRepository.findByEmail(user.getUsername()).getFullName();
       model.addAttribute("username",name);
   }

    model.addAttribute("view", "home/index");
    model.addAttribute("articles", articles);

    return "base-layout";
}
```

And it worked. However i want to use it everywhere and now I can use it only in "/". Please advice how can I modify the code, so I`ll be able to use username in all templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class annotated with [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) which indicates the annotated class assists your `Controller`. Then create a method  `@ModelAttribute` which will set the common attributes, shared by all (or most) of your controllers.

For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class UserControllerAdvice {

  @ModelAttribute
  public void addUserAttribute() {

   Object currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

   if ("anonymousUser".equals(currentUser.toString())) {
       model.addAttribute("username","GUEST");
   } else {
       UserDetails user = (UserDetails) currentUser;
       String name = this.userRepository.findByEmail(user.getUsername()).getFullName();
       model.addAttribute("username",name);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and sorry for the question, should I create @ControllerAdvice as a new file in controller folder or I should add it in the controller?

Comment: Glad you figured out, I was afk. Could you please accept the answer?